# Opening a .jpg with Fireworks so that the canvas fits

Tags: adobe-fireworks

Is it possible to open a `.jpg` in Fireworks so that the canvas size will automatically fit it?

At the moment I have to get the dimensions of the image, create a canvas of this size and then drag the image into it. It's just one of those little annoying things, but it all adds up...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fireworks **always** opens `.jpg` files and all other bitmap formats, with a canvas that fits exactly to image dimensions. The canvas can only be different for editable vector formats like it's native `.fw.png` (just `.png` for earlier versions) and some others like Photohop **.psd**.

**Auto fit**

If you want canvas dimensions to match all content (bitmap/vector or anything) there is a 1-click button: Deselect anything (for ex. click outside canvas), and then click `Fit Canvas` in the `Properties` panel.

This works also perfectly if you are trying to import `.jpg` files on existing canvases by dragging the file in it, pasting it, etc.

**New image**

When you are creating a new image, I suggest to copy the bitmap to the clipboard. If you do this, when you create a new canvas `File > New`, the dimension fields will already be filled for you.